# Changing the Map Projection of a DEM File using gdalwarp?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I have downloaded the moons dem from: https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub

I want to change the projection to create a new orthographic map with

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=ortho +lat_0=90 +lon_0=90" input.tif output.tif
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Invalid dfSouthLatitudeDeg
ERROR 1: Invalid dfSouthLatitudeDeg
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_operations: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body
ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `PROJCRS["SimpleCylindrical Moon",BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_Moon",DATUM["D_Moon",ELLIPSOID["Moon",1737400,0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]],PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CONVERSION["unnamed",METHOD["Equidistant Cylindrical",ID["EPSG",1028]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8823]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["False easting",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]' to `PROJCRS["unknown",BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",6326]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8901]]],CONVERSION["unknown",METHOD["Orthographic",ID["EPSG",9840]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",90,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",90,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["False easting",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]'
```

gdalinfo gives me the folling output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: F:\ATLAS_OF_SPACE\Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.tif
Size is 92160, 46080
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["SimpleCylindrical Moon",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_Moon",
        DATUM["D_Moon",
            ELLIPSOID["Moon",1737400,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Equidistant Cylindrical",
            ID["EPSG",1028]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-5458203.076608000323176,2729101.538304000161588)
Pixel Size = (118.450587600000006,-118.450587600000006)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-5458203.077, 2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-5458203.077,-2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 5458203.077, 2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 5458203.077,-2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=92160x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
  Offset: 0,   Scale:0.5
```

Comment: I´ve figured i might need to define the -s_srs but i can not find the projection "SimpleCylindrical Moon" in the gdalwarp documentation

Comment: What is the gdal version that you have used to change the projection of Lunar DEM?

Answer (score 4):

after some research i did the following:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=eqc +R=1737400" -t_srs "+proj=ortho +lat=90 +lon_0=0 +R=1737400" input.tif output.tif
```

So basically what caused the error was the -s_srs definition. Since it was the moons dem I had to specify the Radius by +R=1737400. Hope this helps!

Comment: for the different projections is found some infos, here https://proj.org/operations/projections/index.html