# Georeferencing Moon photos and LRO DEM but how to model the curvature of the Moon?

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis2threejs, moon

I tried to search for solution to this, but I could not find it. However, if this matter has been dealt somewhere here, please forward me to a correct thread.

**To summarize:**

I am using QGIS and Qgis2threejs plugin to create 3D models from mine and my astroimager colleagues' photos of the Moon utilizing LRO DEM. However, I lack the curvature of the Moon in my models and I would like to add it if possible.

**Software:**

QGIS 3.10.13 (Coruna, LTR), Qgis2threejs 2.5

**Details:**

I utilize LRO mission DEM (https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub) and Lunar photos taken e.g by me. This way I can easily do georeferencing between my images and LRO DEM and create a 3D models running in web browser showing Lunar surface features and elevation. However, with large Moon mosaics it would be nice to get the curvature of the Moon taken into account so that the horizon would curve instead of the horizon being completely flat. I do not know how / if Moon curvature can be parameterized into the model.

**Examples:**

(1) This shows a model in which almost a complete strip of the Moon along the terminator from south to north is modeled in 3D using QGIS and Qgis2threejs. *The model shows the surface features (elevation) but lacks the curvature of the Moon which would be clearly seen in this kind of a large area model.* Please note that the z-axis (elevation) has been scaled with a factor of 1.5 to show the elevation in a bit more visual way. The model may take some time to load (typically done within 1 minute or less) but should be working with many browsers. [Model can be opened here.](http://www.elisanet.fi/astropages/3Dclipped/)

(2) This is provided as a reference only: A smaller area model does not require modeling the curvature of the Moon as these kind of models are OK as they are. However, if possible, also this model could possibly benefit if the curvature could be modeled. [This model can be opened here.](http://www.elisanet.fi/astropages/Ptolemaeus15x/Ptolemaeus15x)

**What have been tried:**

I have no idea how to implement the Moons's curvature into my models. I have searched a lot but I haven't found a solution for the issue. Thus, I have to ask from those who are more capable users than me. *Please note that I only know the basics of QGIS and am not in any way an advanced user.* I read e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347060/changing-the-map-projection-of-a-dem-file-using-gdalwarp), but I am not sure how to e.g. modify the DEM (LRO DEM geotiff) to take into account the Moon's curvature.

**What am I looking:**

A solution, hopefully within QGIS or Qgis2threejs, to take into account the curvature of the moon into my 3D models generated via Qgis2threejs and exported to be run via web browser. I am not looking a solution that requires e.g. Blender or similar to create the curvature of the moon unless I still can utilize the web browser based representation which Qgis2threejs exports (which are pretty awesome). Hopefully such a process of taking the curvature of the Moon into account could be accomplished within QGIS.